# Como ordeno uma Lista Complexa?

Tags: c#, lista, linq, expressões-lambda, class-library

Como faço para ordenar uma lista complexa ? 
Tenho essa lista abaixo e preciso ordenar por **NomeTipo** e **NomeSubTipo**:

```
    public class Tipo()
    {
        public int IdTipo {get; set;}
        public string NomeTipo {get; set;}
        public List<SubTipo> NomeSubTipo {get; set;}    
    }

    public class SubTipo()
    {
        public int IdTipo {get; set;}
        public int IdSubTipo {get; set;}
        public string NomeSubTipo {get; set;}   
    }

    List<Tipo> ListaTipo = new List<Tipo>();

    ListaTipo[0].NomeTipo = "LISTA XYZ"
        ListaSubTipo[0].NomeSubTipo = "B"       
        ListaSubTipo[1].NomeSubTipo = "A"
        ListaSubTipo[2].NomeSubTipo = "C"
    ListaTipo[1].NomeTipo = "LISTA BLA BLA"
        ListaSubTipo[0].NomeSubTipo = "B"
        ListaSubTipo[1].NomeSubTipo = "C"
        ListaSubTipo[2].NomeSubTipo = "A"
    ListaTipo[2].NomeTipo = "LISTA TATATA"
        ListaSubTipo[0].NomeSubTipo = "C"
        ListaSubTipo[1].NomeSubTipo = "B"
        ListaSubTipo[2].NomeSubTipo = "A"

List<Tipo> lreturn = new List<Tipo>();
    lreturn = ListaTipo;

    lreturn.OrderBy(x => x.NomeTipo).OrderBy(x => x.ListaSubTipo.OrderBy(m => m.NomeSubTipo)).ToList();
```

Ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

Comment: Você está criando classes que de lista só tem o nome. Eles contém listas, isso é totalmente diferente, ou transforma elas em lista ou compara só as listas. Qual quer?

Comment: Exato.. o erro que está recebendo não é bem por querer ordenar por mais de uma coluna.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141891/at-least-one-object-must-implement-icomparable

Comment: @Maniero acho que minha dúvida não ficou clara edite o post acredito que ficou mais claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que o quer é algo deste género:

```
List<Tipo> ListaTipo = new List<Tipo>();

ListaTipo.Add(new Tipo()
{
    NomeSubTipo = new List<SubTipo>()
    {
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "B" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "A" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "C" }
    },
    NomeTipo = "LISTA XYZ"
});

ListaTipo.Add(new Tipo()
{
    NomeSubTipo = new List<SubTipo>()
    {
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "B" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "C" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "A" }
    },
    NomeTipo = "LISTA BLA BLA"
});

ListaTipo.Add(new Tipo()
{
    NomeSubTipo = new List<SubTipo>()
    {
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "C" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "B" },
        new SubTipo() { NomeSubTipo = "A" }
    },
    NomeTipo = "LISTA TATATA"
});

List<Tipo> lreturn = ListaTipo.OrderBy(x => x.NomeTipo).
    ThenBy(y => y.NomeSubTipo.OrderBy(z => z.NomeSubTipo)).ToList();
```

Acho que o `ThenBy` resolve o seu problema.

Comment: para que é isso mesmo vou adaptar aqui ao meu código e darei um retorno. obrigado desde já!

Comment: Tem [AQUI](https://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/thenby-operator-part-14) uma boa explicação sobre o uso do `ThenBy`.

Comment: Perfeito @João Martins ! Funcionou ! Obrigado !